# LLamar a una funcion php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Buenas tengo la siguiente duda tengo la siguientes funciones `PHP` en un archivo, la cosa es que quiero que al apretar un boton (eliminar) se llame a la función eliminar y elimine el registro.
Como se puede hacer eso sin llamar a una `funcion js`.
Saludos

```
// funciones.php
function eliminarUsuario($rut){
$consulta ="DELETE FROM usuario WHERE rut ='$rut' ";
$conexion = conectarServidor();
    $query = $conexion->query($consulta);
    if ($query) {
        echo "Eliminado Correctamente";
    }

    else{
        echo "Error";
    }

}

formularioEliminarUsuario.php

 <button type="submit"   class="btn red">Eliminar</button>
```

Comment: y por que no quieres usar js? si con este lenguaje puedes hacer una llamada AJAX para que no se recargue la página mientras se hace el proceso de eliminación

Comment: Ahí como lo haría con un llamado a ajax y de ahi que me lleve a la función PHP que quiero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un form para enviar los datos por medio de POST/GET, se envia la informacion y no requiere javascript: (aunque cambia de pagina)

```
<form action="eliminar.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="rut">
    <button type="submit"   class="btn red">Eliminar</button>
</form>
```

Mientras tanto, el archivo destino contendria algo asi:

```
<?php

include_once('funciones.php')

if($_POST && $_POST['rut'])
{
    eliminarUsuario($_POST['rut']);
}
```

Este archivo simplemente llama a la funcion si existe la informacion deseada (en este caso por medio de POST). Cabe notar que este archivo tambien se puede acceder mediante js sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Tu `button` debe estar dentro de una etiqueta `form` desde la cual se indica a que archivo se va llamar cuando el submit se ejecute.

```
<form action="funciones.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="valor">
<button type="submit"   class="btn red">Eliminar</button>
</form>
```

En tu pregunta no especificas de donde tomas el valor de `$rut` pero asumo que es un campo del mismo formulario.

Añade una sección de código en tu archivo `funciones.php` donde captures el valor y posteriormente mandas llamar la función.

```
if(!isset($_POST['valor'])){
   eliminarUsuario($_POST['valor']);
}
```